# Conditional Expectation of Response Variable given Predictor Variable in Statistical Modeling

Tags: statistics, expected-value, regression, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I'm a bit confused about the implication of the following:

> Suppose we are given a set of data points $(X_i, Y_i), i=1,2,...,n$, where $X_i$ is the predictor variable, and $Y_i$ is the response variable.
>
> - In the context of statistical modelling, we are interested in expressing $Y$ as
>   $$Y_i = s(X_i)+\epsilon_i$$
> - This implies the assumption
>   $$\mathbb{E}(Y_i|X_i=x_i)=s(X_i)$$

I understand that $\epsilon$ is a constant and that the expected value of a constant is zero. However, I do not understand why the expectation of $s(x)$ would be $s(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$E[\epsilon_i|X_i]=0$$ is a common assumption in regression. $\epsilon$ is refers to the noise.

\begin{align}
E(Y_i|X_i=x_i) &= E[s(X_i)+\epsilon_i |X_i=x_i] \\
&=E[s(X_i)|X_i=x_i] +E[\epsilon_i |X_i=x_i] \\
&=E[s(x_i)|X_i=x_i] +0 \\
&=s(x_i)
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain why [()|=]=()? It makes intuitive sense but I don't understand how this would make sense mathematically as E[X]= $$\int xf(x)\, dx$$ for continuous functions.

So [()|=]=$$\int s(xi)*p(s(xi)|Xi=xi)\, dx$$

Comment: $s(x_i)$ is a constant, you can take out a constant from the integration and the density function would integrate to $1$.